# How to use ensureIndex with AdvancedDatastore by specifying a collection name?

Tags: mongodb, morphia

In morphia you can use `@Index` annotations to create automated indexes for `@Entity` classes. I am trying to create these indexes by specifying a collection name but couldn't find a way to do it. Using `AdvancedDatastore` you can save an `Entity` into any collection you want, but is it possible to ensure indexes on a specified collection rather than the default collection of the `Entity`.

```
advancedDatastore.ensureIndexes(Entity.class); // This will create indexes on the mapped Entities.
```

I am looking for a way to do the following, but I didn't see any method similar to below one, is there a workaround to achieve this:

```
advancedDatstore.ensureIndexes("exampleCollection", Entity.class); //create indexes of Entity.class for the exampleCollection.
```

Comment: Out of interest: Why can't you annotate it inside the entity?

Comment: I already annotated the Entity with indexed fields, therefore when I call ensureIndex on the mapped datastore, it creates indexes on the default collection of the Entity. But I want to create the indexes on a different named collection than the default name of the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can extend the `AdvancedDatastore` interface and the `DatastoreImpl` concrete class to add `ensureIndex*` methods with the extra argument. We do this in our organization and it works.

There is also a pending pull request to add this feature directly to Morphia here: https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/pull/541. If you are willing to build your own Morphia jar, you can use the patch listed there.